# Preventing serialisation

Tags: matlab, serialization

I have a Matlab class where implementing serialisation and deserialisation would be painful, and not needed.
Therefore, I have overloaded `saveobj` as follows:

```
    function sobj = saveobj(self)
         sojb = [];
         error(['atmlab:' mfilename ':nostoring'], ...
            ['You tried to store %s %s.  Loading is impossible, ' ...
             'therefore I refuse to store.  Sorry.'], ...
             class(self), self.name);
    end
```

Unfortunately, when I test this, Matlab tries to be helpful and turns the warning into an error (twice for some reason):

```
>> save('/tmp/test.mat', 'X')
Warning: While saving an object of class 'SatDataset':
You tried to store SatDataset amsua.  Loading is impossible, therefore I refuse to store.  Sorry.
(Type "warning off atmlab:SatDataset:nostoring" to suppress this warning.) 
Warning: While saving an object of class 'SatDataset':
You tried to store SatDataset amsua.  Loading is impossible, therefore I refuse to store.  Sorry.
(Type "warning off atmlab:SatDataset:nostoring" to suppress this warning.)
```

I can turn the warning into an error using an [undocumented feature](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/trapping-warnings-efficiently/):

```
>> warning error atmlab:SatDataset:nostoring
>> save('/tmp/test.mat', 'X')
Error using save
While saving an object of class 'SatDataset':
You tried to store SatDataset amsua.  Loading is impossible, therefore I refuse to store.  Sorry.

Unexpected error status flag encountered.  Resetting to proper state.
```

But this is not satisfactory, as I don't want to rely on undocumented features and I certainly don't want to force users to do so.

**How can I effectively throw an error, prevent users from trying to serialise objects from my class?**

---

By request, a minimum example to reproduce the situation:

```
% in TestClass.m
classdef TestClass < handle
    methods
        function sobj = saveobj(self)
            sojb = [];
            error('Unable to store %s objects', class(self));
        end
    end
end

% on the interactive prompt:

>> t = TestClass();

>> save('/tmp/fubar.mat', 't');
Warning: While saving an object of class 'TestClass':
Unable to store TestClass objects 
Warning: While saving an object of class 'TestClass':
Unable to store TestClass objects
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to mark all properties as `Transient`, and let the object effectively have an invalid state that is the result of saving/loading. It's remarkably hard to prevent MATLAB from saving your data, and your workaround might significantly interfere with your users' workflow.

Answer (score -1):

Your code actually throws the error, you should replace your call of `error()` by `warning()`

Comment: No.  My code does not throw the error, my code throws a warning even though I call `error`.

Comment: And changing the call to warning doesn't solve the problem anyway?

Comment: The problem is that I cannot throw an error, because Matlab changes the error into a warning.  Changing it into a warning does not solve the problem of being unable to throw an error.

Comment: Could you past the complete code somewhere, I'm really puzzled by this one.

Comment: I added a full example to the question.